# Javascript Prime Factorization code freezes with large numbers

Tags: javascript, primes

I made this prime factorization program that works really well.The only problem is that, when the input is a large number it freezes the browser. My goal is to make the whole calculation last longer, and not freeze the browser. I have tried several methods to fix this. Firstly i tried to use the `async` + `await sleep(ms)` (I typed await sleep within the for loops, because i think they are causing the over-calculation problem) but for some unknown reason it didn't gave an answer at all. I also tried splitting the function into three smaller functions (one for each `for` loop) and use `setTimeout` for each one of them, and this didn't work as well. I know, that probably there are more simple prime factorization programs out there, but i would like to work on this one, since i figured it out myself. By the way, the first function that is called is `factor1(num)`

```
function factor1(num) {
    if (primecheck(num)){
        document.getElementById("resultingz").innerHTML = num + " is prime";
    }else{
        var finalito = [];
        factor2(num, finalito);
    document.getElementById("resultingz").innerHTML = finalito.toString();
    }
}

function factor2(num, arrada){
    var factors = [];
    var factornums = [];

        for (coun = 2; coun <= num/2; coun++) {
            if (num % coun == 0) factornums.push(coun);

        }

        for (i=0; i < factornums.length; i++){
            if (primecheck(factornums[i])){
                factors.push(factornums[i]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < factors.length; i++){
            rightnow = factors[i];
            while (num % rightnow == 0) {
                arrada.push(factors[i]);
                rightnow = rightnow * factors[i];
            }
        }

    }   

function primecheck(num){
    var primestate = true;
    for (coun = 2; coun <= Math.sqrt(num); coun++) {
            if (num % coun == 0) primestate = false;
        }
        return primestate;
}
```

Comment: Define "large number". And where is it freezing? Debugging should easily be able to tell you that.

Comment: it starts freezing the browser when i enter numbers with more than 6 digits.

Comment: And the line that it "freezes" is:  for (coun = 2; coun <= num/2; coun++) {

Comment: @NiXt By "freezing", do you mean that the browser becomes unresponsive for a (more or less) short time, or that it completely stays frozen forever?

Comment: Please show us the `await sleep` solution you tried, it should work just fine.

Comment: Depends on the number. If it is 6-8 digits it will freeze for about 10-30 seconds. But, any number with more than 10 digits will freeze the browser completely.

Comment: i just added an async in front of the faunction factor2,   and an await sleep(5) within its for loop

Comment: @NiXt have you also await factor2(..) ?

Comment: Do you mean if i typed await in front of factor2 when i call it? If you mean that , no i didn't, and i have used `async` before, and i didn't need to type await when i called the function

Comment: @NiXt async functions return a promise when called. You need to *await* that promise, or do sth *.then*

Comment: so i just have to type await before i call it?

Comment: If you mean that , i just tried that, and the function doesn't run at all, don't know why.....

Comment: @NiXt yep, e.g. async function factor1(..){ ... var finalito=[]; await factor2(..);...}

Comment: well, i have typed all the words and commands i need to, and it still doesn't show any results.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements:

```
function factor2(num, arrada){
    for (coun = 2; coun <= num/2; coun++) {//one loop instead of three
        if (num % coun == 0 && primecheck(coun)){
          var rightnow=coun;
          while (num % rightnow == 0) {
            arrada.push(coun);
            rightnow = rightnow * coun;
          }
        }
    }
}   

function primecheck(num){
   var primestate = true,num=Math.sqrt(num);//performance improvement
   for (var coun = 2; coun <=num; coun++) {
        if (num % coun == 0){
         primestate = false;
         break;//stop loop if false found
       }
    }
    return primestate;
}
```

And you can easily loop asynchronously if you replace a simple for loop:

```
for(var counter=start;counter<max;counter++){
 code;
}
end();
```

With a pseudo recursive function:

```
(function iterate (counter){
  if(counter>=max) return end();//end is a callback

  code;

 setTimeout(iterate,0,counter+1);//next tick, continue with counter+1
})(start);//start the function with a start value
```

Comment: First of all, i have never never used pseudo recursive functions and i don't know how they work, so i would like to explain a bit more on that. Also, i just tried the code with the improvements you proposed, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @NiXt, yeah i will add ab explanation, however *did not work* isnt helpful for me...

Comment: well, it doesn't give the correct answer, for example i just tried 50, and the answer was 2,5,5,10

Comment: @NiXt and youre shure your function returns sth different?

Comment: yes , i checked both of them for the same numbers. My function returned 2,5,5

Comment: @NiXt looks like theres some magic cross influencing through the global *coun* going on. Im not shure how this works :/